# Combined HTML, PHP and Javascript indenting and syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: php, html, vim, syntax-highlighting, indentation

I use vim for web development. These are almost always .php files, which also contain HTML and sometimes Javascript. While working in a block of PHP, indenting works fine. The syntax highlighting is okay, but only really useful for the PHP-code. When I want to edit an HTML block, I usually switch: `:set ft=html`, so that highlighting and indenting work well for that. Of course, I keep switching back and forth, which is time-consuming. I'd like to have all three languages' highlighting and indenting intelligently combined. Being able to `=G` the whole file at once and have it work for each block according to its own rules would be fantastic.

While I know that "I can do this myself", I somehow doubt that I'm the first person wanting this, and I'm looking for an existing solution.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but what about [Better indent support for php with html.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Better_indent_support_for_php_with_html)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help you.. 
https://github.com/2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm

and Why dont you use gedit as the editor its light weight and supports well for various file types. just a suggestion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As far as gedit goes, I know plenty of people who like it, but I've been using vim for five years and I don't think I'll be switching soon :)